Important GitHub Pages related issue with OneSignal service worker installing
Simply script tries to get script from my GitHub Page root, I think I set up OneSignal correctly.
How to fix it?
Maybe there is a way to set "default" path for OneSignalSDK.sw.js?

Error:
[Service Worker Installation] Installing service worker failed TypeError: ServiceWorker script at
https://mandi-os.github.io/webdevelop.guide/OneSignalSDK.js?appId=777-777-777-777-777&sdkVersion=160204
for scope https://mandi-os.github.io/webdevelop.guide/ encountered an error during installation. [ServiceWorkerManager.js:294:12]

GET https://mandi-os.github.io/OneSignalSDK.sw.js? // <-- HERE
appId=777-777-777-777-777&sdkVersion=160204    [HTTP/2 404  9917ms]

Uncaught (in promise) Se: Registration of a Service Worker failed.

Code:
<!-- Push notifications service worker -->
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/web/v16/OneSignalSDK.page.js" defer></script>
<script>
  window.OneSignalDeferred = window.OneSignalDeferred || [];
  OneSignalDeferred.push(async function(OneSignal) {
    await OneSignal.init({
      appId: "777-777-777-777-777",
    });
  });
</script>


If its matter I replaced real appId.

You can use serviceWorkerParam in your config to set a different path
<!-- Push notifications service worker -->
<script 
src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/web/v16/OneSignalSDK.page.js" defer> 
</script>
<script>
  window.OneSignalDeferred = window.OneSignalDeferred || [];
  OneSignalDeferred.push(async function(OneSignal) {
    await OneSignal.init({
      appId: "777-777-777-777-777",
      serviceWorkerParam: { scope: "/myPath/myCustomScope/" },
      serviceWorkerPath: "myPath/OneSignalSDKWorker.js",
    });
  });
</script>

source

Now script init is:
await OneSignal.init({   appId: "777-777-777-777-777",   notifyButton: {   enable: true,   },   serviceWorkerParam: { scope: "/webdevelop.guide/" },   serviceWorkerPath: "/webdevelop.guide/OneSignalSDKWorker.js", });
But still I'm getting error:
GET https://mandi-os.github.io/OneSignalSDK.sw.js?appId=5e8f7ba1-92ef-4043-9ac3-162ff48d9b48&sdkVersion=160204 [HTTP/2 404  140ms]
